# Wordpress ignoring passed in shortcode argument value and uses default argument value instead

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I have a short code that is supposed to return an argument value that is passed in through the short code. However instead of returning the argument it simply returns the default argument.

Here is an example

```
//Returns store id
function getStore($atts){
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
      'storeId' => 'defaultStore',
   ), $atts));

    return $storeId;
}

add_shortcode('storeName', 'getStore');
```

Then I add the following shortcode to a post.

```
[storeName storeId="another store name"]
```

However insted of seeing the following string

```
another store name
```

I get the following default string

```
defaultStore
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: so looks like that shortcode attribute has to be in all lowercase. As soon as I used all lowercase "storeid" instead of "storeId" everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

so looks like that shortcode attribute has to be in all lowercase. As soon as I used all lowercase "storeid" instead of "storeId" everything worked fine.